# Put many heatmap images in one single slide

Tags: r, heatmap, cowplot

I have 3 heatmap plots generated using CRAN package heatmap. I want to put these three images in one slide then I used the following command

```
cowplot::plot_grid(mfs, mfs_ma, mfs_fe,ncol= 3, labels=LETTERS[1:3])
```

but it return me

```
Warning messages: In as_grob.default(plot) :Cannot convert object of class pheatmap into a grob
```

Therefore,how I can put these three images in one slide.

Comment: For cowplot::plot_grid, input must be ggplot  object.

Comment: Or use `par(mfrow = c(1, 3))`, then plot 3 plots.

Comment: well, I did that already but didn't put them in one slide. It just plots each one  by one

Comment: Can you provide link to the package, and your code to create mfs, mfs_ma, mfs_fe objects

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/a/31768236/680068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your heatmaps `mfs`, `mfs_ma`, `mfs_fe` are `pheatmap` objects.
Consider the following simple example:

```
library(pheatmap)
test <- matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
mfs <- mfs_ma <- mfs_fe <- pheatmap(test)
```

You can arrange the 3 heatmaps into a single plot using:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(mfs$gtable, mfs_ma$gtable, mfs_fe$gtable,
                   ncol= 3, labels=LETTERS[1:3])
```

or

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs=list(mfs$gtable, mfs_ma$gtable, mfs_fe$gtable), 
                        ncol= 3, labels=LETTERS[1:3])
```

[image]

Comment: will this work for complexheatmap objects? where my row dimension are different ,and I want them just like the solution you had given

Comment: @PesKchan Interesting question...! Please, post your question on stackoverflow (with a good, simple, reproducible example).

Comment: I figured out `gb<-grid.grabExpr(draw(H1_high))` this converts the complexheatmap object which can be used for gridplot